# Open an emacs file from terminal

Tags: emacs

I want to open emacs + an emacs file directly in the terminal, the file in question, how should I go about it?

Comment: Why are you not satisfied with `emacs` followed by the file name?

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using `putty` I assume you want a non-X version of Emacs:

```
emacs -nw test.txt
```

will open `test.txt` in a non-window version of Emacs.

If you need to open test.txt on a particular line and column use:

```
emacs -nw +5:8 test.txt
```

This will set your cursor to column 8 on line 5 (or at the end of that line if it is not long enough).

Comment: I would perhaps add that in some distros, there's a package called emacs-nox.  If you install it, then you can just type `emacs-nox file` or are even able switch permanently to non-X version via `alternatives --config emacs`.  Or perhaps `update-alternatives`, that really depends.

Comment: @MiroslavFranc You are right, and that is the case on my system (Ubuntu 12.04). At this point I was (am) however not even sure this answers the OPs questio.